# Didn't my book draw this figure wrongly?

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, vectors, physics, classical-mechanics

**Question:**

A body of $20\ lb-wt$ is suspended by two strings that are $6ft$ and $8ft$ long, their other ends being tied to the extremities of a rod of length $10ft$. If the rod was so held that the body hangs just below its midpoint, find the tensions of the strings.

**If the rod was held parallel to the ground:**

[image]

**If the rod was tilted so that C and D points were aligned (according to me):**

[image]

**If the rod was tilted so that C and D points were aligned (according to my book):**

[image]

**My experiment:**

[image]

Using the above apparatus, I attempted to simulate the problem in the question. I found it impossible for the bottle/weight to move towards the midpoint of the stick by tilting the stick towards the shorter string (this is what my book claims through its figure). I found the bottle moving towards the midpoint of the stick when I tilted the stick in the opposite direction i.e. towards the longer string. So, that's why I think the book's figure is wrong.

**My question:**

1. Isn't the book's figure wrong? Didn't they tilt the rod in the
   opposite/wrong direction?

Comment: Your second diagram looks basically like the book's diagram, except that you made the $8 \ \text{ft}$ rod shorter than the $6 \ \text{ft}$ one. Switching the names of these two sides results in a mirror diagram similar to the book's.

Comment: @RobertLee I edited the question.

Comment: In the book, the point $D$ is not the midpoint of $AB$, so the picture is imprecise. However this is unimportant. Their procedure is correct, you need to tilt the rod so that the point $A$ goes down, and point $B$ goes up.

Comment: I would suggest you to retry the experiment with a ball, instead of a bottle ,in my opinion it would give much clearer results.

Comment: @Kolja "In the book, the point D is not the midpoint of AB"- do you mean that their figure was not completely accurate/ to scale as in $AD\neq DB$?

Comment: Also, to be noted - the rod, and the two strings form a fixed triangle which cannot be changed. You can draw the triangle, draw a vertical line between $D$ and the point $C$, and then rotate it until said line is vertical.

Comment: Also," ....found the bottle moving towards the midpoint of the stick when I tilted the stick in the opposite direction i.e. towards the longer string...." I think the situation you are in your experiment the longer string will slack.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic Yes, I meant that the figure was not completely accurate, but the discrepancy is minimal, and the angle should be changed just by a little bit. In the end it would look almost the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your strings are not tightened. This is why your experiment does not work.
2. You can solve the problem in a different way. Draw the triangle $ABC$. It will have the same shape as the final triangle irregardless of how you tilt the rod. Then draw the line between $D$ (the midpoint of $AB$) and the point $C$. Now rotate the figure until the line $DC$ is vertical, and the rod $AB$ is facing north. This is the correct positioning of the rod. Afterwards you can compute the angles and find the forces.

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant answer!